# Conditionally matching two databases in python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a collection of objects of foods and restaurant and I need to match all object food object to the corresponding restaurant. 
I implemented a naive solution that has time complexity O(n*m), where n and m size of the food and restaurant database respectively.

```
def match_products(self):
   self._restaurant_dict= self._init_restaurant_dict()
   for food in foods():
        for restaurant in self._restaurant_dict.keys():
            if self._matched(restaurant , food ):
                self.mached_candidates[restaurant].append(food)

def _init_restaurant_dict(self):
    res_dict= {}
    for product in restaurants():
        res_dict[restaurant] = []
    return res_dict

def _matched(self, restaurant , food ):
    return restaurant.id == food.id
```

The restaurant and food are defined as follow:

```
class Structure:
    _fields = []
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) != len(self._fields):
            raise TypeError("Wrong args number")
        for name, val in zip(self._fields,args):
            setattr(self, name, val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in vars(self).items())

class Restaurant(Structure):
    _fields = ["id","name","owner"]

class Food(Structure):
    _fields = ["id","descriptions","calories"]
```

Methods foods() and restaurants() are generators. 
So how can I speed up this algorithm?

Comment: Do `foods()` and `restaurants()` yield their contents in any particular order?  Maybe using dictionaries mapping `id` to the `Structure` so you only have to iterate over one of the lists once.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. So the solution was that easy. I am a fool!

Answer (score 1):

use the id as the hash value for a lookup table.

```
lookup_table = dict()
for food in foods():
  if food.id not in lookup_table:
    lookup_table.update({food.id: [food]})
  else:
    lookup_table[food.id].append(food)
matched_candidates = {restaurant : lookup_table.get(resturant.id, []) for restaurant in restaurants()}
```

Or something like that.  O(N+M)

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Any idea how to make similar matching using a little bit more complicated condition, for instance, same id and same first name's character?

Comment: Sure, but I would encourage you to think about what makes a good hash value.  What makes this work is that there is a good "One to many" relationship between the food id's and the restaurant id's.  If you complicate it, it might not be as fast.  I'll add an example here, where It further buckets on the first letter of the name, but think about when a database would be more appropriate than trying to do these relationships in code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to clarify, I'm assuming that you want to be able to select a food by a restaurant ID and the first character of the food name.  So, say that "Papa-hut" had an id of 42 and you wanted a "pizza", you's look it up by key `42p`
Why does this work?  Because, I expect that the `restaurant.id` field to be a unique identifier, and that **any unique string concatenated to a string, is still unique**. Therefore, complicating the `restaurant.id` field will provide more specific searches into the lookup table.  But, will require more accesses to get the foods out.  You can experiment with this trade-off.  [Wiki on hash tables Advantages/Drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Advantages)

```
matched_candidates = dict()
for food in foods():
  if food.id not in lookup_table:
    matched_candidates .update({''.join(food.id, food.name[0].lower()): [food]})
  else:
    matched_candidates [food.id].append(food)

  matched_candidates.update({ restaurant : [] 
                            for restaurant in restaurants()
                            if restaurant not in matched_candidates.keys()
                           })
```

The update is to add resturants that may not have any foods in the foods() generator.  This is still O(N+M).

I have to be honest here, that this feels wrong to me.  That it kind of requires a special knowledge of both the foods and the restaurants to be able to access the table.  But, the lookup is fast, so maybe that's all you care about.